# Does it make sense to apply feature selection on a data set that has undergone principal component analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, feature-selection, data-mining, scikit-learn

I have a data set that consists of credit card transactions. This data set contains only numerical values which are the result of principal component analysis.

I'm currently trying to improve my models by doing hyper-parameter tuning. But I also came across feature selection methods such as SelectKBest, SelectFpr, etc that are in the scikit-learn library.

Would it make sense to do feature selection on the data set considering that the data has already been reduced through principal component analysis?

Comment: How do you define 'sense'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not enough information provided to offer a suggestion.  Was PCA run on the applicants (objects) or the features?  Recall, a lot of principal components will be meaningless if their associated eigenvalues are low (less than one is a common default if the correlation matrix was used).

Also, what are you trying to do with the data obtained from PCA?

If PCA was run on the features, then there are no "features" if you only have the PCA-based data.  Reason is because information from highly correlated (original) features will be collapsed together in the major PCs (1st, 2nd, 3rd,....), and you now only have PCs.   So the answer is yes, you can run feature selection on the PCs for predictive analytics.   If you also know the eigenvalues for the 28 features, then you can pre-filter the PCs to use for feature selection by using those PCs whose eigenvlaues are >1.

Comment: I got this is data set from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud). This data set has already been put through PCA before I did anything with it. To quote, "It contains only numerical input variables which are the result of a PCA transformation. Unfortunately, due to confidentiality issues, we cannot provide the original features and more background information about the data. Features V1, V2, ... V28 are the principal components obtained with PCA, the only features which have not been transformed with PCA are 'Time' and 'Amount'."

Comment: See modified answer.